# javax.persistence PROPERTY access custom getter/setter names

Tags: hibernate, jpa

The implementation of my entities is generated and I have little control over it. The main problem I am facing is that boolean fields getter method has a different naming convention: `is<FieldName>()`.

```
public class Bookmark {
    /**
     * @generated
     */
    public boolean isIsPrivate() {
        ...
    }

    /**
     * @generated
     */
    public void setIsPrivate(boolean newIsPrivate) {
        ...
    }
```

}

The particular implementation lacks actual fields on the entity, I know it sounds crazy but it is how it is. As such, I need to use PROPERTY access. Since I can't modify how the code is generated, I am doing this in a orm.xml mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd">

<persistence-unit-metadata>
    <xml-mapping-metadata-complete/>
</persistence-unit-metadata>
<package>org.hibernate.ogm.backendtck.type.ogmemf.impl</package>
...
<entity class="Bookmark" access="PROPERTY">
    <attributes>
        <basic name="isPrivate"/>
    </attributes>
</entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

However, this will result in hiberante looking for a `getIsPrivate()` method, that does not exist.

Since I need to use PROPERTY access but my get methods don't follow the JavaBeens conventions, is there any way I can persuade hiberante to look for a specific method or pattern so I can map the `is<FieldName>()` methods?

Comment: can't understand share the code please.

Comment: Ummm... `is<FieldName>()` already follows the convention, unless it's a `java.lang.Boolean` as opposed to a primitive `boolean`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per JPA spec section 2.2

```
In this case, for every persistent property property of type T of the
entity, there is a getter method, getProperty, and setter method
setProperty. For boolean properties, isProperty may be used as an
alternative name for the getter method. [2] 

For single-valued persistent properties, these method signatures are:
• T getProperty()
• void setProperty(T t)
```

Since your property is boolean then `isProperty` is a valid name and your JPA provider should observe it. If it doesn't then you should raise a bug on it.